# how to import mysql database to toad for mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, toad

In the import wizard of toad it shows only csv , xml, excel csv etc.. format to import data. there is no  option to import .sql file to toad for mysql. please help thanks in advance.

i get this error when i try to import
[image]

Comment: you may try with Navicat: http://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-for-mysql or phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

In the import wizard, you should see an "Add Query" button. This should allow you to upload a .sql file. There is also a database migration wizard I believe in Toad.

Comment: i get this error when i try to import from Add Query "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accesscodes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREME' at line 1"

Comment: Have you modified the .sql file at all? Where did you export it from?

Comment: i exported it from phpmyadmin, now i get this. " Variable 'collation_connection' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'"